# tableau change dimension to attr(dimension) in dashboard

Tags: tableau-api

In a worksheet, if I have a dimension as second dimension in a row label I can "collapse" that dimension with `ATTR()` by selecting `Attribute` in the menu:

[image]

However, this menu is only available on the worksheet view.  How do I enable the user to accomplish this switch on the dashboard?

Comment: With a parameter and a calculated field. Details left as an exercise for the reader :-) ... Seriously, that's all you need. Hint, your calculated field can access the parameter value and choose to call ATTR() or not.

Comment: I've tried that.  `ATTR` is an accumulator, so formulae can't return variously `ATTR([field])` and `[field]`.

Comment: You're right about not using ATTR() in the calculated field, I shouldn't answer in a hurry. A posted a solution that actually works

Answer (score 1):

Create a boolean valued parameter, call it say **Should Expand**. You can choose readable aliases, such as "Expand" for True and "Collapse" for False.

Show your parameter control and customize the look as desired

Create a calculated, call it, say **Collapsable Foo**, where Foo should really be the name of your true second dimension. Define it as

```
if [Should Expand] then [Foo] end
```

Make sure **Collasable Foo** is a dimension and use it as desired, presumably in place of Foo. You can edit the aliases for **Collapsable Foo** to set Null to a single blank to improve the way text appears when collapsed.

Comment: I'm currently using this possibility.  `if [collapse] then [foo] else "" end`.  However, I discovered the menu item in my worksheet that allowed me to switch between [foo] and ATTR([foo]), and I was hoping to make that available on my dashboard.  It's possible that that's impossible, so if nothing turns up I'll accept this answer.

Comment: You can display the parameter control, Should Expand, on your dashboard to allow your users to choose. I don't think the setting to switch between dimension and attribute itself can be exposed.